# Making angular service for complex Firebase queries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-promise

How to transform queries like the one bellow to the Angular service which will return either promise that would resolve to the `result` or the `result` itself without promise? 
I guess that I need to chain promises somehow, but can not figure it how, never done it.

```
var result = [];
var groups = $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref().child("users/" + uid + "/leagues"));
groups.$loaded().then(function (data) {
  _.each(data, function(one){
    firebase.database().ref().child('leagues/' + one.$id).once('value', function(snapshot) {
      result.push(snapshot.val());
    });
  });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it something like this that you want ?

```js
function getGroups() {
  return $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref().child("users/" + uid + "/leagues")).$loaded();
}

function getDataGroups(groups) {
  return $q.all(groups.map(function(one) {
    return firebase.database().ref().child('leagues/' + one.$id).once('value');
  }));
}

getGroups().then(getDataGroups).then(function(results) {
  //blabla
});
```

Note : I've never played with firebase (so maybe I've done some errors), but after some quick research `$loaded()` and `once()` are both returning a Promise.